# where is adobe acrobat reader

Tags: unity, unity-dash

I wanted to make it easier to use some programs. I wanted them to be on my desktop.  I found them using Dash and dragged them to the desktop.  When I now try to execute them, I get the message that they are not trusted applications.  I searched and found a post that says to Right click - Properties - Permissions and check Make executable.  The problem is that I can't because I am not the owner - root is.  How do I fix this?
If I drag it from an executable place, it should be executable in the new place.

Comment: I don't understand the link between your question (Acrobat Reader) and its explanation. Could you please edit your question to reformulate it?

Comment: Do these programs load when you click on the icon in the Dash or if you fix the icon to the Launcher? What programs are they?

Answer (score 1):

First make sure you've installed acroread with the Software Center or Synaptic -- it will be installed as executable. Right click any PDF file and acroread should be an option to open with although it's likely not the default which will be Document Viewer. If you select Preferences you'll be able to use the Open With tab to make acroread the default. It sounds like you were trying to drag a PDF file onto an Adobe Acrobat Reader icon to open it. I'm not sure that will even work, depends on the application. Normally you wouldn't place an application on the desktop or in the launcher, you'd be dragging a .desktop file that launches the application. Those .desktop launchers are located in /usr/share/applications. There you'll find a launcher you can drag to the launch bar or copy and paste on the Desktop.